# SQL Server Windows Authentication NTUSERNAME is different to Windows Login

Tags: sql-server, active-directory, authentication, sql, windows-authentication

An employee at a client has just got married and as a result they have changed her details, login name et al.,  in Active Directory (AD).

The problem is SUSER_NAME() in procedures and the NTUSERNAME in SQL Server Profiler still shows her original maiden name.

All connections by this login are made using Windows Authentication and there aren't any indvidual logins set up in SQL Server, access is granted through the "Everyone" AD group.

Is there some kind of cache in SQL Server or a storage of login name somewhere that I don't know about that might be causing this to happen.

I'm informed by the client's IT team that every possible location in AD has been changed to the new name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Windows Local Security Authority (LSA) caches SecurityIdentifiers (SIDs).  These cached values will retain the old username.

More information:

**The LsaLookupSids function may return the old user name instead of the new user name if the user name has changed on a domain controller**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946358

Comment: Thank you, for all my searching I couldn't find something like this. For anybody that comes across this question in the future the "member computer" described in the article in my case is the server that hosts SQL SERVER. It is also possible to remove the new registry key afterwards if you wish to continue using the cache.